# Save a column conversion for reuse in a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

There's a `SELECT` in a stored procedure that has some nested `case-when` blocks, and this thing comes up about 5 times in different `or` blocks:

`CONVERT(DATE,  ADJDOH) <= CONVERT(DATE, ADJDOT)`

These fields can have a `DATETIME`, be blank (an empty string) or `NULL`, or, an invalid value, which makes the `CONVERT` function fail. Is there any way I can convert these fields once and then be able to do the comparisons, or null checks more easily than using the `CONVERT` function so many times?

In the following example row 4 gives an error if the date is invalid.

```
CREATE TABLE repro (
    id int,
    date1 varchar(10),
    date2 varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO repro values
(1, '12/31/2021', '12/30/2021'),
(2, NULL, '12/14/2021'),
(3, '',''),
(4, '12/30/202', '12/30/2021')

SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE,date1) as D1,
    CONVERT(DATE,date2) as D2
from repro 
where 
--id = 1
--id = 2
--id = 3
id = 4

drop table repro
```

Comment: You could fix the table schema and make the datatype of the column be DATE. Then you don't have to convert them all the time.

Comment: `cross apply` - but please provide a [mre] i.e. the smallest query possible which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: A view or computed column?

Comment: If you're getting invalid dates like `'12/30/202'` then you probably want to use [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post as a code block. Your example query doesn't reproduce the issue, because you don't convert the same column twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CROSS APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#l-using-cross-apply) + [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) are what you want here. `CROSS APPLY` allows you to carry out any calculations/conversions/etc in one place without having to duplicate the logic. `TRY_CONVERT` allows you to detect and/or recover from bad data.

```
SELECT 
    D.Date1 AS D1
    , D.Date2 AS D2
FROM repro 
CROSS APPLY (
  -- Perform any calculations/conversions here, once
  VALUES (TRY_CONVERT(DATE,date1), TRY_CONVERT(DATE,date2))
) AS D (Date1, Date2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can

- Add a [_computed column(s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)
- Define a [*view*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-ver15) on the table that provides the needed column

You'll still need to handle the bad data though, one way or another, though. But either of these gives your a persistent way of providing the date conversion without need to repeat the logic over and over again.

[Frankly, I'd clean the data in the table, and then put a `check` constraint on the column to ensure that bad date fails any insert or updates. Or, better, convert the column to `date` and have done with it — though that is likely to break existing code that expect the column to be `char`/`varchar`.